# Jenkins unable to save a new or edit an existing Maven Project Configuration

Tags: maven, jenkins, configuration

Whenever i try to save a new Maven Project in Jenkins i can press apply or save without anything happening or any error messages showing up. When i switch from Chrome to Firefox i get a "Error" popup which just contains an empty http body.
The logs dont show any problems or errors. The weird thing is Freestyle project do work just fine.

What i've tried :

-Update Jenkins & Plugins

-Rollback some plugins to older versions

-deinstall some unused plugins

-set java home for maven

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You are gonna have to list war and plugin vers to be of use. Maybe check https://issues.jenkins.io ?